# Is the subgroup order always a multiple of it's generators order?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, finitely-generated

To be more specific, I'm looking on $S6$ right now.
I want to show that the subgroup generated by: $\langle a=(1234),b=(3456) \rangle$ has order $16$, meaning the multiple of it's generators (EDIT: this is wrong see comments).

This is clearly correct if the generators commute, as we just need to choose 2 numbers from 0 to 3, for the powers of the generators.

But what happens when the generators don't commute, like in the example? I haven't been able to find a clear rule for this case.
What confuses me is that when they don't commute, $a^i*b^i$ and $b^i*a^i$ could be different for some $i$, resulting in a larger subgroup.

Comment: There is no general rule. Two elements of order two can generate a group of any even order, or even an infinite group. In your example you can take advantage of the fact that $a^2$ and $b^2$ do commute.

Comment: The subgroup you defined has order $120$ and is isomorphic to $S_5$ and (more naturally)  to ${\rm PGL}(2,5)$. It arises in the Rubik cube in the action on corner pieces.

Comment: Got it, thanks.